A function falls below default machine precision
I am trying to plot a function that becomes too small in a certain range (< 10^-320) and can no longer be calculated. Is there a way to change the precision so that it works and the log-log plot does not look truncated?
F[d_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 1\), \(10\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - 
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(d\ Log[10]\)])\), 
FractionBox[\(9\ \(9!\)\), \(\((10 - k)\)!\)]] \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(k\)]
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(k - i\)] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(i\), \(d\)]\), \(\(\((k - 
          i)\)!\) \(i!\)\)]\)\)\)/\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 1\), \(10\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(k\)]
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(k - i\)] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(i\), \(d\)]\), \(\(\((k - i)\)!\) \(i!\)\)]\)\);

ListLogLogPlot[Table[1 - F[d], {d, 1, 15000}], Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.8,
ImageSize -> Large, Ticks -> {Automatic, {1, 10.^-50, 10.^-100, 10.^-150, 10.^-200,
10.^-250, 10.^-300}}, PlotRange -> {{1, 10000}, {10^-330, 1}}]

Actually I am interested in finding the minimum of this function, which should be somewhere in the range 1200 < d < 1400. What is the correct way of doing it without losing accuracy?

'10^-320)' is not from the real world.

Well, how real-world is number theory? We are talking about very small probabilities here, and it's not my fault that we live in a world where decimal number system is popular. After falling below 10^-320, this function recovers and has a limit of 1 at p->oo, which I find fascinating.

Your expression can actually be resolved by Mathematica (ie. it can resolve the sums). So instead of F[d] :=  write F[d] = . Then you shouldn't get the errors. Afterwards, try with Minimize[F[d], d].

Alternatively, FindMinimum[F[d], {d, 1800}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000] gives d -> 1829.20474... as the point of minimum ... This can also be seen from the plot: ListPlot[N[Table[{d, Log@F[d]}, {d, 1800, 1850, 1/2}], 50],   Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All].

Yes, it looks like Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000}, N[F[1829], 20]] does what I want.

Somehow I still cannot make it work within the ListLogLogPlot command:
ListLogLogPlot[Table[Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000}, N[F[d], 20]], {d, 1,     10000}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 10000}, {10^-400, 1}}]

Still, I am satisfied with the solution you proposed that takes Log explicitly instead of using the LogPlot. I would expect that LogPlot should do the same, but apparently it doesn't. Even if I set the precision to infinity, it truncates the plot whereas your version plots it down to the minimum.
